# Generate multiple Excel file in a loop

Tags: php, phpexcel

In my code, I do a loop like this

```
foreach($_POST['checkXls'] as $val){     
      GenererXlsFile($val,$mois,$annee_en_cours);    
  }
```

The function GenererXlsFile() create a downloaded excel file and his end is :

```
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);  // On redimensionne automatiquement la taille de la colonne du code
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(true);  // On redimensionne automatiquement la taille de la colonne des noms et prénoms    
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("$libelle_classe");    
    $titre_doc="BORDEREAU DE COMPOSITION de la classe $libelle_classe pour le mois de $libelle_mois au titre de l'année académique $libelle_annee.xlsx";    
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');  
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$titre_doc.'"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
    //header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');   
    exit;   
    $objPHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets(); 
    unset($objPHPExcel);
```

In the loop,
I have at least 3 line to treat but only one excel file is genarated and correctly and then my code stops here. I do not know why. Please can someone help !? Thank you

Comment: If you're sending files to the browser, you can only send a single file at a time: if you need to send multiple files, then you need to zip them into a single file and then send that one file.... note that this is simply how http requests work

Comment: Thank you Mark Baker, I will try this and come back again ! Best regards !!!